# Git History page modification issue - overlap of text

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add a task ID column into Git History view. But get the following issue

[image: History error]
[image link](http://www.uploadimage.in/di/RLVH/history_error.jpg)

if you see the image, the Last column(Task id) is overwriting on itself with an offset of one character. It looks like some thing to do with number of columns, as when i experimented by rearranging, the last column was always having the issue.

If anyone has any idea on this please let me know.

code added in **CommitGraphTable** class

```
private void createColumns(final Table rawTable, final TableLayout layout) {

...//existing code in the method
final TableColumn task = new TableColumn(rawTable, SWT.NONE);
task.setResizable(true);
task.setText(UIText.CommitGraphTable_TaskIdColumn);
// task.setWidth(50);
layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(5, 100, true));
}
```

Code added in **CommitLabelProvider** Class

```
public String getColumnText(final Object element, final int columnIndex) {

...//existing code in the method
if (columnIndex == 6){
    return (taskId);//$NON-NLS-1$
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a code i missed out to change. marked by XXX comment

```
private void createPaintListener(final Table rawTable) {
    // Tell SWT we will completely handle painting for some columns.
    //
    rawTable.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
            if (0 <= event.index && event.index <= 6)
                    //XXX changed the index comparison from 5 to 6
                event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
        }
    });
```